# Robot Framework Locator not able to find locator

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have been trying to find the locator for my testing in robotframework. Below is my html element block and I am unsure of what is the "stable" locator and test on this. I would sincerely appreciate the xpath or any stable locator.

```
<div class="sc-jXcwIi bnswfh cosmos-layout-child" data-cosmos-key="stack-layout.item"><div data-cosmos-key="row-layout" class="sc-bQCGiA fFRDIw"><div class="sc-fXgAFM cosmos-layout-child" data-cosmos-key="row-layout.item">deploy-extension</div><div class="sc-fXgAFM cosmos-layout-child" data-cosmos-key="row-layout.item"><span data-cosmos-key="text" type="allcaps" class="sc-fujyUd cWWTbP">MACHINE TO MACHINE</span></div></div></div>
```

I have tried the locator

```
Click Element                       xpath://div[contains(text(), "deploy-extension")]
```

But this is giving me error.

```
export existing tenant               | FAIL |
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="sc-fXgAFM cosmos-layout-child" data-cosmos-key="row-layout.item">...</div> is not clickable at point (431, 355). Other element would receive the click: <p data-cosmos-key="paragraph" class="sc-dlnjPT corHA">...</p>
  (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.66)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

focus on the element first.

```
Set Focus To Element       xpath://div[contains(text(), "deploy-extension")]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with various locators as below,

```
//div[contains(text(), "deploy-extension")]//following::span[contains(text(),'MACHINE TO MACHINE')]
//span[@text='allcaps'and contains(text(),'MACHINE TO MACHINE')]
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-xpath-in-selenium-with-python